# Change listBox color if

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime, listbox

I need help with changing the color of specific item(s) in a listBox.

My code :

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        List<string> lst;


        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy  HH:mm";
            lst = new List<string>();   
        }

        private void BindList()
        {
            lst = (lst.OrderByDescending(s => s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(" "), s.Length - s.LastIndexOf(" ")))).ToList();
            listBox1.DataSource = lst;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {       
                string s = textBox1.Text + ", " + Convert.ToDateTime(this.dateTimePicker1.Value).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm");
                lst.Add(s);
                BindList();

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lst.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            BindList();    
        }

        private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy  HH:mm";        
        }       
    }
}
```

I add text from TextBox1 and time and date from DateTimePicker1 to listBox1.

I need the item in listbox to turn red if it is less than 1 hour from current time.

What I've tried so far:

```
DateTime current = System.DateTime.Now.AddHours(+1);
DateTime deadline = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value);

do
{
   // missing this part
}
   while (current <= deadline);
```

If you can finish this or have a different solution, it would be great.

Thanks !

Comment: See [ListBox.DrawItem Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize your form, you'll want something like this:

```
listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
listBox1.DrawItem += listBox1_DrawItem;
```

The first line indicates that the list box's items will be drawn by code that you supply, and the second line assigns an event handler that will do the drawing. Then you just have to create the `listBox1_DrawItem()` method. Something like this should do:

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    // DrawItemEventArgs::Index gives you the index of the item being drawn.
    var itemText = listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString();

    // Get a red brush if the item is a DateTime less than an hour away, or a black
    // brush otherwise.
    DateTime itemTime, deadline = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
    var brush = (DateTime.TryParse(itemText, out itemTime) && itemTime < deadline) ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Black;

    // Several other members of DrawItemEventArgs used here; see class documentation.
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.Graphics.DrawString(itemText, e.Font, brush, e.Bounds);
}
```

Refer to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drawitemeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details on the various members of `DrawItemEventArgs` that I'm using here.

Comment: You'll have to be specific about what kind of problem you're having.

Comment: The color does not change, maybe the problem is in 'DateTime itemTime, deadline = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
    var brush = (DateTime.TryParse(itemText, out itemTime) && itemTime < deadline) ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Black;'

Comment: That may be. Looking back at your original code, it looks like your list items _contain_ a DateTime, but some other data as well. In that case, DateTime.TryParse() will always fail. You'll just need to replace that code with something that extracts the DateTime portion of the list item text and converts it to a DateTime.